# Liferay 6.2 failed on startup with 500 error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm starting a new and freshly downloaded Liferay 6.2 tomcat bundle, but this exception occured :

```
 EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0] with root cause
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalInstances._getDefaultCompanyId(PortalInstances.java:344)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalInstances.getDefaultCompanyId(PortalInstances.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getDefaultCompanyId(PortalImpl.java:1897)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(PortalUtil.java:515)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.validhostname.ValidHostNameFilter.doFilterTry(ValidHostNameFilter.java:38)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:183)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-1][code_jsp:?] {code="500", msg="", uri=/}
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note that I keep the default configuration and I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE GA3 and Java 1.8.0_251.

Could provide me some helping path ?

Thanks

Comment: You might have more luck on the Liferay community sites - this question is not programming related, but to software (quite outdated, by the way) that you downloaded and started. Stackoverflow's focus is on your own programming problems (see [help/on-topic]). If you have _any_ reason to be on 6.2 CE, you should be on [GA6 with the patch](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1). Hunting bugs in outdated software is quite pointless. 6.2 GA3 was released in January 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `JDK 8u251` resolved the problem.